# Minifying my App strips essential classes

Tags: android, proguard, minify, bundling-and-minification

My app runs fine when launched via USB in Android Studio. Though when I create an `apk` file and install that, the app crashes immediately on launch with a `ClassNotFoundException`. Investigating further I disabled minifying, changing

```
minifyEnabled true
```

to

```
minifyEnabled false
```

in `build.gradle`.

Without minifying, the `apk` file works. However, I don't want to refrain from minifying my app. How does the minifier work? Why does it strip essential classes of my app? How can I make the minifier to include all my classes?

My `proguard-rules.pro` file is empty except for comments.

Comment: You should check out this paragraph again: [Customize which code to keep](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code). In some cases, R8 can't know that you need some code because it isn't called directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
-keep public class MyClass
```

to `proguard-rules.pro` did the trick. In the end I had to keep two classes this way. They both have something in common: They're both added via

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

in xml layout, not in code with `FragmentManager`. Those are the only classes added this way.